# My program is crashing when trying to access a struct member in C

Tags: c

I can't figure out why my program is crashing after accessing
`parametres.DUREE_APPUI_BOUTON_PTI`

```
    case A5_PRESS_TOUCHE_PTI:
#if LOG
        char pui_text[64];
        sprintf(pui_text, "A5_PRESS_TOUCHE_PTI: %d Size DUREE: %d;", parametres.BOUTON_APPEL_PTI, sizeof(parametres.DUREE_APPUI_BOUTON_PTI));
        logout(&pui_text);
#endif

    xcmp_send_pui_brdcst(0, 0, parametres.BOUTON_APPEL_PTI, PRESS, 0, 3);
    if (APPUI_LONG == parametres.DUREE_APPUI_BOUTON_PTI) // crashes here
    {
        DELAY_EVT(A5_RELEASE_TOUCHE_PTI, 1300);
    }
    else
    {
        DELAY_EVT(A5_RELEASE_TOUCHE_PTI, 500);
    }
    break;
```

Here is how I define it:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t DUREE_APPUI_BOUTON_PTI;
} stuct_parametres;
stuct_parametres parametres;
```

I set the value as such:

```
parametres.DUREE_APPUI_BOUTON_PTI = APPUI_LONG;
```

After adding a breaking point the values are displayed as such:

```
APPUI_LONG VALUE is 0x00000001
DUREE_APPUI_BOUTON_PTI is 0x01
```

The program doesn't crash when I replace

```
xcmp_send_pui_brdcst(0, 0, parametres.BOUTON_APPEL_PTI, PRESS, 0, 3);
```

with

```
xcmp_send_pui_brdcst(0, 0, 0x9400, PRESS, 0, 3);
```

Can someone help me explain the issue and how to fix it?

Comment: I do not think the crash can be explained with the information provided in the question. Please, provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: "APPUI_LONG VALUE is 0x00000001" is wrong. `APPUI_LONG` is a macro, it is replaced by 1 when the preprocessor is called. You should not have `APPUI_LONG` in you final code. Or you have variable and macro that have the same name, which can be problematic

Comment: There is something you're not telling us. This works: https://godbolt.org/z/WahqTaYar. Please [edit] and clarify. Also read this: [ask] and this [mcve].

Comment: The crash is likely in the code that is executed when that `if` condition is true. Or in the code directly before that `if` statement

Comment: No it is crashing exactly at this condition. When I replace the condition with 

APPUI_LONG == 0 or APPUI_LONG == 1

The program doesn't crash.

Comment: @CharlesSemaan you need to show more code, there is nothing wrong in the code you show, the problem is elsewhere. What is your platform? Do you have a debugger?

Comment: Microship studio here is the recording of the breakpoint https://streamable.com/57jtm3

Comment: I added the function where it crashes

Comment: @CharlesSemaan obviously you can inspect `parameters` with the debugger but when you access it via your code it crashes. You should add this crucial information into the question, maybe with a screenshot of the debugging session where you're inspecting `parameters`. Also add all other useful information into the question such as your platform, your compiler etc. etc.

Comment: Well I thought the issue is related to the comparaison itself so I added the type defs and the debugger values and even the sizeof values. I will try to add more info that can be useful.

Comment: What happens in the record, the interrupt for the UARTA is triggered, but the function for the UART is not implemented so becomes an infinite loop. I suppose that this is the function called just before, which activates the UART.

Comment: For some reasons when I replace `xcmp_send_pui_brdcst(0, 0, parametres.BOUTON_APPEL_PTI, PRESS, 0, 3);` with  `xcmp_send_pui_brdcst(0, 0, 0x9400, PRESS, 0, 3);` the program doesn't crash.

Comment: So you replace an 8-bit value with 0x9400, a 16 bit integer that `parametres.BOUTON_APPEL_PTI` cannot represent. That sounds very wrong to me... I would be surprised if the crash doesn't happen inside `xcmp_send_pui_brdcst` instead. When compiling with optimizations I've often seen discrepancies between source code and object code that can make it harder to pinpoint exactly which line of code is causing a crash.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `xcmp_send_pui_brdcst` with `parametres.BOUTON_APPEL_PTI` as argument, it seems that it is blocking access to my parametres struct for some reason.

A workaround for the issue is by extracting the values from parametres struct to local variables then used them as such:

```
case A5_PRESS_TOUCHE_PTI:;

    const uint8_t duree_appui = parametres.DUREE_APPUI_BOUTON_PTI;
    const uint16_t bouton_pti = parametres.BOUTON_APPEL_PTI;

    xcmp_send_pui_brdcst(0, 0, bouton_pti, PRESS, 0, 3);

    if (duree_appui == APPUI_COURT)
    {
        DELAY_EVT(A5_RELEASE_TOUCHE_PTI, 500);
    }
    else
    {
        DELAY_EVT(A5_RELEASE_TOUCHE_PTI, 1300);
    }
    break;
```